# Replacing subString in an array with bash

Tags: bash, find-and-replace, array

What I got:

```
array[0]="Programm is Running"
array[1]="programm is down"
```

What I want:

```
array[0]="Programm is \e[0;32mRunning\e[0m"
array[1]="programm is \e[0;31mDown\e[0m"
```

This will make things a little more colorful (using the `echo -e` command), at least I hope so.
I tried to replace this with:

```
array[$i]=${array[$i]//"running"/"\e[0;32mrunning\e[0m"}
array[$i]=${array[$i]//"down"/"\e[0;31mdown\e[0m"}
```

That didnt work. Error Message:

> 0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command.

Why does that happen? What do I need to different?

Comment: Works for me, even if it doesn't produce colourful output. What version of bash are you running?

Answer (score 0):

it appears you have the case wrong Running vs running, the following works for me

```
    array[0]="Programm is running"
    array[1]="Programm is down"

            for i in 0 1; do
            array[$i]=${array[$i]//"running"/"\e[0;32mrunning\e[0m"}
            array[$i]=${array[$i]//"down"/"\e[0;31mdown\e[0m"}
    done
    echo ${array[0]}
    echo ${array[1]}
```

produces

```
    Programm is \e[0;32mrunning\e[0m
    Programm is \e[0;31mdown\e[0m
```

with echo -e instead of just echo, it produces the correct colored text, however, this would be easier to just fix by hand than re-fix it every time it is run.

Comment: thanks for your Input!
I thought of that myself - but as im doing my  apprenticeship (learning to be something / im not a native speaker) to be an IT guy I'm not allowed to alter that program that originally produces the output.

Comment: oh, got it. Good luck!